# How to send M-. to terminal (multi-term) in Emacs

Tags: emacs, terminal, ansi-term

I am trying to send the command `M-.` (i.e. `<ALT> .`) to a terminal that is running in [multi-term](http://www.emacswiki.org/MultiTerm) in Emacs. For reference, `M-.` is typically bound to insert the last argument of the previous command in a terminal (i.e. `yank-last-arg` / `insert-last-argument`)

I have the following set up:

```
(require 'multi-term)
(multi-term-keystroke-setup)
(setq multi-term-program "/home/john/sw/zsh/bin/zsh")

(setq term-bind-key-alist
    (list
    ( cons "C-c C-j" 'term-line-mode)
    ( cons "C-c C-k" 'term-char-mode)
    ( cons "C-p"  'term-send-raw)
    ( cons "C-n"  'term-send-raw)
    ( cons "C-a"  'term-send-raw)
    ( cons "C-e"  'term-send-raw)
    ( cons "M-b"  'term-send-backward-word)
    ( cons "M-f"  'term-send-forward-word)
    ( cons "M-d"  'term-send-forward-kill-word)
    ( cons "C-k"  'term-send-raw)
))
)

# Make sure yanking works:
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-y") 'term-paste)))
```

I have tried adding:

```
( cons "M-."  'term-send-raw)
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

In case it is useful, here's the list of commands that seem to have the term prefix and that are defined in `term.el`

```
term-send-M-x
term-send-backspace
term-send-backward-kill-word
term-send-backward-word
term-send-del
term-send-down
term-send-end
term-send-eof
term-send-forward-kill-word
term-send-forward-word
term-send-home
term-send-input
term-send-insert
term-send-invisible
term-send-left
term-send-next
term-send-prior
term-send-quote
term-send-raw
term-send-raw-meta
term-send-reverse-search-history
term-send-right
term-send-up
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have `multi-term` to test it, but you can try using `term-send-raw-meta` instead of `term-send-raw`:

```lisp
(setq term-bind-key-alist
    (list (cons "C-c C-j" 'term-line-mode)
          ; ...
          (cons "M-."  'term-send-raw-meta)))
```